# jquery at caret plugin doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I implement very big script logic using jquery plugin at caret(http://code.google.com/p/jquery-at-caret/), but now when I finish it I realized that it only works in Firefox and Chrome, it doesn't work in Internet Explorer.

I realized that function "setCaretPosition" is that which is not working in IE.

I am getting only in IE "o is undefined", you can see in code snippet below that this
is occurring from 79-89 lines of plugin code, but I can't figure it out how to fix this.

I create very small code snippet to just replicate this bug:
http://www.mediafire.com/?xxt0medyci61690

Comment: Which version of IE you are facing issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified the code in the plugin

```
 setCaretPosition: function(pos) {
  var f1, f2, o;
  o = this[0];
  if (o.setSelectionRange) {
    o.focus();
    return o.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
  } else if (o.createTextRange) {
    f1 = function () {
      return o.focus();
    };
    setTimeout(f1, 10);
    f2 = function() {
      var range;
      range = o.createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd('character', pos);
      range.moveStart('character', pos);
      return range.select();
    };
    setTimeout(f2, 20);
    return pos;
  }
}
```

Please check, I have tested in IE8, IE9 & Firefox.

Comment: I test it now in IE7 and IE8 and it works.
Thanks man you save my time.

Answer (score 2):

The function f(o, pos) is causing the issue. Try to make individual functions and then call them. There are two functions define with same name `f`.